# syntax error `(" unexpected in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

i'm coding a simple bash script and i found this error syntax error at line XX `(' unexpected
my code:

```
function myfun(){
   echo XXXX
   echo YYYY
   read choice
}

choice=$(myfun)
```

where is the error. i used the ShellCheck and no errors were detected.

Comment: `error syntax error at line` please post the full error message, verbatim, without hiding the line number (what for?) (if so, which line?). Please make sure your scripts doesn't have DOS line endings.

Comment: Here `myfun(){`, there have to be space, like this `myfun() {`.

Comment: "unexpected (" usually indicates you're running bash code with /bin/sh

Comment: If you want the user to select a choice from a menu, use the `select` statement: `select choice in XXXX YYYY; do [[ $choice == "" ]] || break; done; echo "$choice"`

Comment: Even in `bash`, the `function` keyword serves no real purpose and can (and should) be omitted).

Comment: @Ivan No, that space is not necessary.

Comment: The `function` keyword was added to support porting `ksh` scripts to `bash`. `ksh` makes a distinction between functions defined with and without the `function` keyword. `bash` simply allows it to be used; it does not affect the definition in any signifiant way.

Comment: @chepner yep, my bad, thank you

Comment: @secretsquirrel I don't see how that makes a difference. In both cases, you have two options; switch to a syntax which is compatible with the shell you are using, or switch to a shell which is compatible with the syntax you are using.

Comment: @triplee, well if the OP accepted the answer below its a moot point; the script doesn't need a shebang if its run as sh script.sh..the code in the accepted answer doesn't run on Ubuntu, there are other problems with the function declaration. I did a version and tested it on Ubuntu and it worked with bash, but with significant changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you are running the script with `bash`. That error is a commonly seen `dash` shell error.

I suspect the first line of your script is not `#!/bin/bash`, i.e. you may have left out the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) line entirely resulting in the default shell being used (which will often be `dash` especially on Debian derived Linuxes where `/bin/sh -> dash`).

Try running this:

```
#!/bin/bash

myfun()
{
   echo XXXX
   echo YYYY
   read choice
}

choice=$(myfun)
```

Comment: Of course, with the pesky `function` keyword out of the way, this simple script is now also completely compatible with `/bin/sh`.